# Host a streaming webcam on website with VLC/Red5 or whatever

Tags: java, html, web, streaming, red5

I currently have a website that i am running at my home based on Java/SpringMVC web server.

I want to stream my webcam to my website so i can connect to it where ever i am from a browser and see my room.

Does anyone know an easy solution/server to use to do this and how to capture this in HTML.

Maybe a guide or sample project or something.  I cant find anything useful/straight forward on Google.

I have already tried Red5/VLC as a media server but have had no luck so far capturing the video on a webpage. (using html5 video tags on chrome.)

I need to have this embedded in my home website. So it has to be browser based

I have decent Enterprise Java skills but streaming video is kind of new to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can stream a webcam to a website via multiple ways.

use Windows media Server/ Flash media Server. Push your webcam to the server by Windows Media Encoder or flash media encoder, and use the server live link to link with your website via any suitable player (like jwplayer).

Use Windows Media Encoder to stream your webcam to anyone without a server involved. when your encoder starts, you will get a URL to view your stream, which you can use to publish in your site.

use third party streaming services, where they give you a publishing point to publish your webcam stream, and use the link provided by them to show it on your website. (check with brighcove or Mogulus by LiveStream

Hope this helps.